# map vs subscribe in @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx-store

I am new to angular2, currently, I am working on a project which using @ngrx/store and subscribe classes. I am confused on map method is not working while subscribe store is working. Please help me in understanding when to use map and subscribe method. The code is below.

```
this.store.select('rating').subscribe(({ topPicks }) => { // code is working });
this.store.select('rating').map(({ topPicks }) => // not working);
```

Comment: Map operation takes a function as input and applies the function to each value emitted by source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable.

In case of subscribe, you are connecting an observable to its observers.In order for an observer to see the items being emitted by an Observable, or to receive error or completed notifications from the Observable, it must first subscribe to that Observable with this operator.

A typical implementation of the Subscribe operator may accept one to three methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, here `this.store.select('rating')` is an Observable. Depends on whether the observable is Hot or Cold, (For more information read this [blog](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html#hot-vs-cold-observables)) observable will start emitting values. In your case, first statement works because you are subscribing to observable. `Map` is just an operator which you can use it on the values emitted by an observable(its does not work as subscriber).

Second statement does not work as there is no subscriber to the Observable. To use map operator, you can do like below:

```
this.store.select('rating').map(/* Do whatever you want to with the emitted values here */).subscribe(({ topPicks }) => {});
```

To know more about operators, you can have a look at [documentation](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#map).